# Value not usable in constant expression alternative pattern

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming

I am looking for an alternative c++ pattern to achieve this:

Read from an option from a file (let's say its either A or B).
In a cycle I want to repeat a call to a template function depending on the option, but I don't want to check the value each time, instead, I want the compiler to generate both possibilities and choose the one with template A if the option is set to A, and with template B if the option is set to B.

If i do this though:

```
Option option = readFromFile("AorB");
for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
{
    performOperation<option>(); // Long but fast function I don't want to define twice
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: the value of 'option' is not usable in a constant expression
```

How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: you cannot ask the compiler to generate or choose anything during runtime, at that point your code should be mature enough to do it himself :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the code weirder and more meta ;) you could play a bit with variadic templates, lambdas and constexpr implicit cast:

```
#include <iostream>

template <char C>
struct Option {
    constexpr operator char() {
        return C;
    }
};

template <char Opt>
void performOperation() {
   std::cout << Opt << std::endl;
}

template <char... Options>
void runOption() {
   char optionFromFile = 'a';
   int dummy[] = {([](auto option, char chosen) {
      if (chosen == option) {
         for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            performOperation<option>(); 
         }
      }
   }(Option<Options>{}, optionFromFile), 0)...};
   static_cast<void>(dummy);
}

int main() {
   runOption<'a', 'b'>();
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bvY2DloCOPrxquMC)

Have fun!

Comment: Awesome! :)
I can't quite comprehend what it is doing though :D
Working hard on demangling what that ... does there :)

Comment: `...` is to expand parameter pack (`Options`). It generates lambda call for each value passed to your `runOption`

Comment: You make an anonymous lambda out of the calls of the possible templates to performOperation, and I think make a zero value out of every one of them by a C style coma operator (?). Then you force the initialization of the templates with the cast?

Comment: Adding [[maybe_unused]] and removing the static_cast from the end works in c++17 :)

Comment: Using comma operator is to trick compiler to let it invoke lambda for each parameter from pack. In c++17 you wouldn't even have to use this trick as it provides more streight-forward way - [fold expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/2676/fold-expressions)

Comment: What do you mean by the `Then you force the initialization of the templates with the cast?`

Comment: I don't know if the compilers can optimize out constructing unused variables.

Comment: Most compilers does it - of course not in debug mode/in -O2(+) :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144679/discussion-between-adam-hunyadi-and-w-f).

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you can't pass a variable to something that expects a compile time constant.

If you've got something that is either "A" or "B" and you're worried about checking for that each time then you could expand the loop/condition yourself:

```
Option option = readFromFile("AorB");

if(option.isA())
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
  {
      performOperationA(); 
  }
else
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
  {
      performOperationB(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: This saves you from repeating run-time check at the expense of repeating a loop, which is a maintenance liability that can be justified only with extensive profiling in extremely rare cases.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - I agree. However, the wording of the question suggest that the poster is worrying about performance.

Comment: I worry about performance, and this is the obvious but error-prone implementation (and also this is the current state of the code I'm using). I was wondering if there is a better approach without defining the same long function twice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `operation` to select the behavior at runtime, then you may want to create a class to encapsulate the behavior that varies. Next create an instance of the class *once* based on the option value A or B. Then inside the loop, you pass the class instance to `operation`.

I've provided an example below that implements OptionA and OptionB in a class hierarchy. If you do it this way, then you don't even need a template at all. But you didn't provide much detail on how the behavior of your operation varies, so I didn't want to assume too much about what you have to work with. The template is only required if you have two unrelated classes that implement an identical interface.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class OptionType {
   public: virtual int calculate( int x ) = 0;
};
class OptionA :public OptionType {
   public: int calculate( int x ) { return x+99; }
};
class OptionB : public OptionType {
   public: int calculate( int x ) { return x*100; }
};

template<class T>
void performOperation( T& option, int x ) {
    // your performOperation is a long function
    // this one is short but shows how the behavior can vary by option
    std::cout << option.calculate( x ) << std::endl;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    // Option option = readFromFile("AorB");
    // pass A or B from the command line
    char option = (argc > 1) ? argv[1][0] : 'A'; // your code reads this from a file
    OptionType* optionObject;
    if( option == 'A' ) optionObject = new OptionA();
    else                optionObject = new OptionB();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        performOperation( *optionObject, i );
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, after reading this properly, I realized that it is useless, the function "calculate" is defined twice here. This answer is useless this way :/

Comment: @AdamHunyadi The answer is not useless, quite the opposite. The entire point of the question is how to have the function `performOperation` act on two different types. Your code did not provide any information about how or why those types are different, or how the operation uses them, so I made a simple example. If you want an answer that's more specific to the classes and operation you're using, you might consider adding the relevant portions of that code to your question.

Comment: My question is specified, that I want to call one function with two different templates (this code can't do that, try making a template <int> version of calculate to see). Also, the code uses a bad practice of declaring something as a template reference (which confuse me when taking the first look) which should be clearly a pointer of the base class.

Answer (score 0):

you can't because the option is a variable, and a template is compile time. the performOperation needs to receive a constant value on the <>.
and since the operations occours on runtime - you need an if.

But you could use the branch prediction to do less work - if you sort the vector before passing to for / if call(value) else call_2(value), it would run much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Template arguments must be known at compile time. At run time, it's too late to instantiate new instances of a template. You will need to force the generation of each instance that may be required at run time and implement some form of dispatching. The simplest approach is to have a dispatching function with a switch. For example :

```
enum class Option {
    Opt1,
    Opt2,
    Opt3
};

template<Option opt>
void Operation() {}

void performOperation(const Option opt)
{
    switch (opt)
    {
    case(Option::Opt1):
        Operation<Option::Opt1>();
        break;
    case(Option::Opt2):
        Operation<Option::Opt2>();
        break;
    case(Option::Opt3):
        Operation<Option::Opt3>();
        break;
    default:
        // Handle however you want
    }
}
```

Another solution would use a map of `std::function` :

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>

enum class Option {
    Opt1,
    Opt2,
    Opt3
};

template<Option opt>
void Operation() {}

const std::map<Option, std::function<void()>> func_map = {
    { Option::Opt1, []{Operation<Option::Opt1>(); }},
    { Option::Opt2, []{Operation<Option::Opt2>(); }},
    { Option::Opt3, []{Operation<Option::Opt3>(); }}
};

void performOperation(const Option opt)
{
    func_map.at(opt)();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood the question correctly.
You could try this way:

for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
{

```
#ifdef A
read("A");
#endif
#ifdef B
read("B");
#endif
```

}

and at compiler level you can choose:
g++ main.cpp -D A
or 
g++ main.cpp -D B

Comment: The OP is asking about a runtime condition. You cannot use #ifdef to select at runtime.

Comment: Yes, this is a run-time check, I want both the options ready. Thanks for the answer though!